# Threading model for UDP/Socket communication in server side

Tags: multithreading, sockets, tcp, udp

In server-side, for one UDP socket file descriptor(received from client connect()), I have to open one thread to read from each client.
So if I have 100 clients connected to a server, then there are 100 threads for this. Is there any other threading model like some thread pool.
Same question goes for TCP as well.

Comment: For UDP, a single thread with a single socket is often sufficient -- just use sendto() and recvfrom() for all your UDP I/O (and avoid send(), recv(), and connect()).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In server-side, for one UDP socket file descriptor(received from client connect()), I have to open one thread to read from each client.

No you don't. You only need *one* thread for reading. You might need multiple *replying* threads, if the replies take significant time to prepare.

> So if I have 100 clients connected to a server, then there are 100 threads for this.

Bzzt. You don't. There is no such thing as 'connected' in UDP.

> Is there any other threading model like some thread pool.

I would certainly use a thread pool for preparing the replies, and sending them.

> Same question goes for TCP as well.

Completely different kettle of fish. You need either:

1. A thread per accepted socket, possibly allocated from a thread pool, or
2. non-blocking multiplexed NIO, again possibly with a thread pool for preparing replies, or
3. Asynchronous I/O.

Comment: Thanks for your answer... I have one more question regarding TCP socket, "A thread per accepted socket, possibly allocated from a thread pool": If I do this from a thread pool, then I have to limit number of client communicating with the server to number of threads in the pool? If not how ? Can you please explain a bit more

Comment: You have an accept loop. You have a blocking thread pool. It blocks while it is full, then it gives you a thread. So then the accept loop can dispatch an accepted socket to a thread, and go back to accept another connection. While it was blocked, it wasn't accepting connections, so the backlog queue was filling up, doing whatever it does when it gets full (which is platform-dependent), and the clients concerned are doing whatever they do when the server's backlog queue is full ... and none of them is actually getting serviced. Which is what you want.

Comment: *Or* you have a non-blocking thread pool that accepts an infinite number of tasks and only despatches them when a free thread is available. From the point of view of the `accept()` loop and the clients, this is less desirable.